# Android: How to make a chart with a slider in Android?

Tags: android, charts

I want to make a time series chart with a slider below that can help me select a segment from the chart. Basically I want the slider to allow me to get the chart values of its two ends.

An example for reference is the chart in *Settings->Data Usage* in Android 4.0 and above. (*I'm adding a link to the image as I lack the required reputation* https://i.stack.imgur.com/negbB.png )

Is there any library or method to achieve the same result?

Comment: did you managed to do this? I need same functionality on custom graph with this horisontal seekbar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 chart libraries for you. Hope for help.
[**MPAndroidChart**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
[**Android Charts**](https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts)

Comment: What I'm looking for precisely is a way to have vertical sliders with a time series chart. This is the particular example I'm referring to http://i.stack.imgur.com/negbB.png

I doubt any of the libraries you mentioned provide the same

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda In MPAndroidChart,can we apply spesific color to individual entry like applying to Dataset?

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda In MPAndroidChart, How to achieve two sliders with values?